# Ember.beforeOberver callback is asynchronous to property change

Tags: ember.js

Context: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/diyirecu/23/edit

Is there anyway to have the Ember.beforeOberver callback run first and then the property changes? Or should I be using a different strategy all together?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can turn that event synchronous... However, I refactored your code to use some simple jQuery patterns (callbacks... I know, very non-Ember of me) that achieve the same thing. The code is clunky compared to what you were looking to achieve, but it works.

Example JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/diyirecu/26/edit

I also changed `popObject` to `removeObject` so that it actually removed the item you clicked on.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: {},
  colors: ['red','blue','green'],
  color: 'orange',

  actions: {
    addColor: function () {
      var color = this.get('color'),
          $ul = Ember.$('ul');

      if (color) {
        $ul.fadeOut(500, function () {
          this.get('colors').pushObject(color);
          this.set('color', '');
          $ul.fadeIn();
        }.bind(this));
      }
    },
    removeColor: function (color) {
      var $ul = Ember.$('ul');
      $ul.fadeOut(500, function () {
        this.get('colors').removeObject(color); //Changed from popObject
        $ul.fadeIn();
      }.bind(this));
    }
  },
});
```